# Should we do something about our meta tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

We have a decent selection of language and technology tags, but we also have many meta tags, such as [refactoring](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refactoring).  A meta tag, at least on here, specifies the OP's *request(s)* in a review, and not much else.  It could especially become problematic if the OP has many requests and tries to apply as many of these tags as possible.  They also cannot stand on their own, unlike language tags (technology tags cannot as well, but these should also stay).  The scope of the site does involve meta-ness, but perhaps we don't need so many, or even any of them.

What do you think?  Should we burninate them all, or just certain ones?  Is there another way we can approach meta tags, if something should even be done about them?

---

Here's the master list of meta tags up for consideration so far:

- <s>[refactoring](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refactoring)</s>
- <s>[clean-code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clean-code)</s>
- [beginner](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner)
- <s>[code-smell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-smell)</s>
- [reinventing-the-wheel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel)
- <s>[readability](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/readability)</s>
- <s>[best-practice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practice)</s>
- <s>[style](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style)</s>
- <s>[code-organization](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-organization)</s>
- <s>[usability](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usability)</s>
- [portability](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portability)
- <s>[idiom](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiom)</s>
- <s>[database-design](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-design)</s>
- <s>[database-schema](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-schema)</s> -> [database](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database)
- <s>[structure](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structure)</s> -> <s>[data-structures](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-structures)</s>
- <s>[dry](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dry)</s>
- <s>[code-reuse](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-reuse)</s>
- <s>[pep8](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pep8)</s>
- <s>[solid](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solid)</s>
- <s>[srp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/srp)</s>

Comment: How about [tag:oop]?

Comment: @nhgrif: It isn't quite "meta enough" (it doesn't directly relate to the site, an example being [refactoring]).

Comment: [tag:control-structures], [tag:conditions], [tag:loop]

Comment: @200_success: Why do you suggest those?  They don't seem as meta as the others.

Comment: @200_success: What do you think about [tag:syntax] and [tag:grammar]?

Comment: [tag:syntax] has some inappropriately tagged questions, but also some interesting ones about syntactic sugar. [tag:grammar] seems to be a more technical variant of [tag:parsing]. We should probably do something about those two tags, but taking more of a surgical than a nuclear approach.

Comment: @200_success: Alright, you may take care of them, and I'll do further edits if necessary.

Comment: @nhgrif [tag:oop] questions often do mention significant concerns about object modelling. However, questions tagged with [tag:classes] seem to be done so for no apparent reason.

Comment: This post was originally about meta-type tags. Can we please restrict the discussion to those. Other tags like scripting, file-structure, and google should have their own separate questions. I'll post the question about google when time permits.

Comment: @ckuhn203: Sorry about that.  Some of those tags came to mind at the same time, and they just got mixed up with this larger process.  I could still remove them from the lists here.

Comment: No worries. Just trying to keep us on track. I did post [a separate question about the google tags](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2131/41243).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The selected meta tags will be burninated in phases, based on usefulness (but may still vary as decisions are made).  This post will be updated as burninations are done, up until the question is tagged as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).**

**Notes:**

1. "Blacklisted" means that a tag can no longer be created by anyone.
2. "→" signifies synonymization, the rightmost tag being the master.

---

**Phase 1:** [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

- <s>[refactoring](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refactoring)</s> - *blacklisted*
- <s>[clean-code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clean-code)</s> - *blacklisted*
- <s>[code-smell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-smell)</s>

**Phase 2:** [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

- <s>[style](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style)</s>
- <s>[code-organization](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-organization)</s>

**Phase 3:** [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

- <s>[readability](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/readability)</s> - *blacklisted*
- <s>[best-practice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practice)</s> - *blacklisted*
- <s>[usability](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usability)</s>

**Phase 4:** [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

- <s>[database-design](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-design)</s>
- <s>[structure](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structure)</s> → <s>[data-structures](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-structures)</s>
- [database-schema](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-schema) → [database](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database)
- <s>[code-reuse](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-reuse)</s>
- <s>[pep8](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pep8)</s>

**Phase 5:** [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

- <s>[dry](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dry)</s> - *blacklisted*
- <s>[solid](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solid)</s>
- <s>[srp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/srp)</s>

Answer (score 22):

I think many of the above can go, but I think these should *definitely* get burninated:

- <s>[refactoring](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refactoring)</s>
- <s>[clean-code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clean-code)</s>
- <s>[code-smell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-smell)</s>

They really add nothing to the question, and they are already naturally ingrained in the review process.  Pretty much every question is about refactoring in some way.  Everyone wants their code to be clean (we're not [PP&CG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)).  Everyone posting code for review has suspicions about it (code-smell), otherwise it wouldn't even be up for review.

Comment: For the sake of continuity… [previous thread on \[refactoring\]](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1048/9357)

Comment: Also related: [tag:dry]

Comment: Also related: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2141/do-we-need-acronym-tags-dry-solid-etc

Comment: i disagree since nowadays we have a clean definition on what 'clean code' does mean and what principles can be violated...

Answer (score 21):

I feel that these are useful and should stay. Users may want to follow or ignore these tags for various reasons. For example: I'm an intermediate level code monkey, so I find if easier to answer the beginner questions.

1. [beginner](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner)
2. [reinventing-the-wheel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel)
3. [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance)

[optimization](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) feels awfully similar to [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) and should probably be a synonym.

The others add no value; all should be considered in any code review. Burn them with fire.

Comment: I don't agree that [tag:reinventing-the-wheel] should stay, but that [has been discussed before](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1508/is-the-tag-reinventing-the-wheel-really-helpful) :(

Answer (score 2):

I feel like [file-structure](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-structure) should not be burned, and is a valid part of a code review (if included with the question).

Take this example:

```
Test/
├── .gitignore
├── README
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── src/
│   ├── audio/
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── web/
│   │   └── ...
│   └── ...
├── build/
└── cmake/
    ├── FindLibSndFile.cmake
    └── FindPortaudio.cmake
```

If there were a better way to structure my files, I would want to know how and why.  Granted, this should not be the *only* thing reviewed; but it is certainly an aspect of a code review.  How the files are structured could also affect the code and how it is programmed.

Comment: I'd like to hear more about why you feel that's a valid part of a code review.

Comment: @ckuhn203 Somewhat expanded on it.

Comment: Ignoring whether it's on-topic or not… If the topic is "source code filesystem layout", then [tag:file-structure] doesn't convey that idea, and the tag needs a better name.

Comment: I presumed the tag had little to do with how I organize my source code and more to do with how I'm dealing with a drive's file structure within my program...

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, the following are points that should already be taken care of in answers. Even if the OP specifies one point of interest, it's reasonable to take care of them all.

**Burn:**

- [refactoring](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refactoring)
- [clean-code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clean-code)
- [code-smell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-smell)
- [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance)
- [optimization](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization)
- [readability](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/readability)

---

It's hard to have an opinion on [beginner](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) and [reinventing-the-wheel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel) because both are acceptable descriptions of a question. However, do they carry the weight of having their own tags?

[beginner](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) seems like something OPs already add in their question without hesitation (as to make sure responses aren't too harsh or complicated).

[reinventing-the-wheel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel) is useful, simply so the fuss of deciding whether the OP knows of the language functionality is eliminated.

Update: I see what's being said about [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance). Since I'm not actively involved with that tag, I was misled and retract my desire to destroy it. Maybe I'm a pyro...

Comment: Not so sure about [performance]. There is a whole class of questions about code that takes _way_ too long to run, and they usually require a completely different algorithm.

Comment: I can get behind all of these except performance. I also wonder if optimization shouldn't be a synonym of that one.