# Do we still need a database tag like [database-schema]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

As part of our [mass meta-tag burnination](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2024/should-we-do-something-about-our-meta-tags?cb=1), we're also considering [database-schema](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-schema).  It also seems closely related to [database-design](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-design), which has been burninated and blacklisted just recently.  We already have a [database](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) tag, which is *not* up for burnination.  I don't think we need very many database-related tags since we already have a site dedicated to this: [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).  I'm also thinking that it may slightly reduce the chances of receiving questions solely about databases (no code), which will get migrated to Database Administrators anyway.

Comment: **NOTE:** The action taken was synonymization, not merging.  I've accepted that answer anyway since I followed a similar course of action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, we don't. Merge them into [database](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) I say.

I just don't really see a need. There is a whole SE site dedicated to DB Administration, and schema-design/database-design is more looking at charts and concepts than code generally.

Comment: Could you please explain your reasoning?  Burnination and merging are both irreversible, so I don't want to get this wrong.

Comment: I just don't really see a need, as you said, there is a whole SE site dedicated to DB stuff, and schema-design/database-design is more looking at charts and concepts than code generally.