# Should we let [dry] dry away?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, blacklist-request

This tag was burninated as part of [this discussion](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2141/do-we-need-acronym-tags-dry-solid-etc), and I've seen it come back a few times after that, including today.  It may be a popular review request, but that doesn't mean it should keep coming back as a tag.  Mentioning such concerns in the question body is already sufficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. I've personally removed this tag at least once since the discussion you mention was marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). I'm sure I'm not the only one. There's no reason to keep burning it over and over. Blacklist it.

Answer (score 11):

Sure. If we intended to delete the tag, and yet it keeps getting recreated, then blacklisting seems like the logical course of action.