# Any [comments] on this burnination request?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Last summer we [burninated a number of meta tags](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2024/41243). These were mostly tags that described what the original poster of a question was concerned about or wanted to have reviewed. I stumbled across the [comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comments) tag this morning and I'm thinking it should go.

From the tag wiki:

> Comments are non-executable remarks embedded in source code that are
>   directed at programmers or that are for documentation. Use this tag to
>   indicate that the comments in the code are a concern (verbosity,
>   helpfulness, or formatting).

Comments are clearly not a technology, nor can I think of a use for this tag that wouldn't reflect someone's concerns about their code. Since we determined that concerns about your code should be stated in your question, what's the use of this tag? Is there one?

Comment: [tag:naming] seems relevant as well, but that can be put into a separate question.

Comment: Ugh @Jamal why did you have to do that to me? Now I want to start cleaning those up too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. This tag is too meta and should be removed. Any possible use for this tag would indicate an OP's concern with the code, not the code itself.

Comment: Agreed, this tag should be applied to all questions containing comments otherwise, which would be.... a lot.