# Let's clean up [cleancode]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, blacklist-request

The tag [cleancode](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleancode) was recreated, so it was not blacklisted the whole time.  Anyway, should it be blacklisted at last?  If so, then I believe it should also apply to the other variant, [clean-code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clean-code).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can find no use-case whatsoever which would require this tag.

We all want our code to be 'better' which implies cleaner as well. If OP is worried about how clean his code is, an explanation in the question would be enough. It doesn't warrant a tag. We don't need [cleancode](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleancode), we don't need [dry](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dry), we don't need any of those. This is just one variant of an old story.

According to [this answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2025/52915) it should have been gone already. Let's finalize the deal and blacklist it this time.