# Should we forever deconstruct [data-structures]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, blacklist-request

This tag was recreated today and was probably also recreated some time ago since its burnination as part of our [massive tag purging](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2024/should-we-do-something-about-our-meta-tags). We already have separate tags for the most common data structures, so there's no reason for this one to keep coming back. Should we finally have this one blacklisted, including a singular [data-structure](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-structure) for good measure (we do already have blacklistings for different variations of certain tags)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Yes, blacklist it.

As stated above:

> We already have separate tags for the most common data structures, so there's no reason for this one to keep coming back.

Additionally, to define a post as being about data structures is too generic to be useful or informational. I can't imagine anyone would follow that tag, as it represents such a broad concept/category.

[image: burn it!]